# How to filter cached query in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, caching, laravel-5.1

Need help/advice with this concept. I have pretty complex fluent query which pulls rows according to users filters.

I was thinking of making unfiltered (only joins, without where/whereIns) query which would be cached, and then somehow filter that cached query according to users need.

There's 2-3 seconds lag when querying db each time form filter changes, so i'm guessing this can perform better.

Now unfiltered query is around 5k rows, and average filtered one brings 500-1000 rows.

Query is around 25 columns with 4 CONCATS, 3 CASE statements and 14 leftJoins.

Is that right way? Any other suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Y

Comment: which system caches the unfiltered results ?

Comment: none yet. I thought Laravel 5.1 Cache, with file driver?

Comment: You can also use the MySQL / MariaDB cache . so you never have old results in it. when you write to a table that you use in your cache result the cache was cleared

Comment: ok, thanks for a tip, i'll look at it. So it's like creating a view?

Comment: @Yuray You can read [How the Query Cache Operates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache-operation.html) from the MySQL manual.

Comment: Ok, so i see cache is flushed every time tables from query are updated. Since there's lot of writing to tables, i guess it will not be performance gain.

Comment: Idea is that some supervisor, pulls data and do some analytics with data for example till today. So i would like to improve performance on "old" data, what is happening now isn't important. And if it is, I thought i would make "refresh" query button, which will "forget" cached query and make a new one.

Comment: Then you can use the [Laravel Cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache) and generate a unique key (ideally based on the query parameters, so a set of filters will be cached the first time but retrieved from cache the second). For clearing the cache you can run the `php artisan cache:clear` command, or if you want to do it programatically you can use `Artisan::call('cache:clear');`.

Comment: Wouldn't be better way to cache unfiltered query? So when user changes filters that filters are applied to cached "table"? Someting like creating excel pivot with db source. Once it is refreshed you are manipulating data via filters without querying db.?

Comment: Caching an entire table's worth of information will eat up quite some memory (even more if you're using Eloquent models), so my suggestion would be not to do so.

Comment: Just filter it with standard laravel collection methods.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [sql view](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp).

Or you can store your filtered data to another database table. And you can update it using a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) automatically.

By the way you can filter your data fastly from database table using sql.

It will be like dbcache, but you will control it.