# Cache queries with filter

Tags: laravel, caching

I'm creating a system that shows users some data with filtering by city, category ... and sorts by some params and has pagination. there are hundreds of cities and categories. If I cache these queries by redis memory goes out of memory? should i use cache or process them normally. Is cache suitable for this one.

Thanks.

Comment: How long are your queries (in seconds)?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981862/how-to-filter-cached-query-in-laravel) once, may this will help you.

Comment: Depends on what your data is. If you cache entire objects, then yeah, your cache will be flooded in minutes.

Comment: I mean that if I have one thousand state for each url then should I use cache? Is it ok and normal?